# Expanding the Relative Momentum-Energy Relationship

Tags: taylor-expansion, physics

I am looking at the relativistic relationship between energy and momentum and I want to use a Taylor expansion to estimate the Energy at very large and very small values for momentum (p).

The equation is $E^2 = p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4$

I know that for small values of p, E is roughly equal to $\frac{p^2}{2m_0}+m_0c^2$, but I do not know how to use the Taylor Expansion to do find what E is roughly equal to at very large values of p. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I would say that you need to provide more (mathematical) details. The setting is not obvious.

Comment: I have updated it with more information. Hopefully it noe makes more sense.

Comment: Ok, at large values of $p$, $E$ is approximately equal to $pc$, as the other term is negligible. Or this is not precise enough?

Comment: That makes intuitive sense, but I was instructed to use a Taylor Expansion and a limit with 1/p somewhere in my process of solving.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?
$$
E = pc \sqrt{1 + \frac{m_0 c^2}{p^2}} \simeq pc (1 + \frac{m_0 c^2}{2p^2} )
$$